# Xamarin Target named 'SignAndroidPackage' not found in the project

Tags: android, xamarin

I am building a android binding project on xamarin studio which builds successfully. However when i include the same in a test project (from reference), I am facing error [Target names SignAndroidPackage not found in the project] in the binding library project. I tried setting up signing keys but no luck.

Any pointers how i can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your stack trace or Image of exception.

Comment: tracking it here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41924